# How to stop a notification saying "Registering to Network" every few seconds?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, notifications, mobile-network

On Samsung Galaxy S2 HD LTE SHV-E120K Android v4.1.2 without a SIM I get "Registering to Network" notification repeatedly.

How to stop?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Enable airplane mode. Wifi will work in this state.